# Removing an item when using Array.prototype.map() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have a variable that contains an array of numbers

```
let numbersArray = [12, 15, 19, 20];
```

When looping over it I want to delete the entry if it is a certain value

```
let numbersArray = [12,15,19,20],
    filteredNumbersArray = numbersArray.map(function(value)
    {
        if(value === 15)
        {
            //delete the value
        } else {
            return value * 2;
        }
    });
```

In regards to using `.filter()`, the value must be mutatable, I have updated the example

I have searched through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but couldn't find anything about removing an element within a `map()`.

<sub>The Rubber Duck didn't help either</sub>

Comment: [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can remove an item, [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a value for each item.

Comment: What you need is filter and not map

Comment: @NinaScholz Ah I see, it seems I missed a detail out of my question which I thought wasn't needed, I require value manipulation as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could filter and then map

```js
var array = [12, 15, 19, 20],
    result = array
        .filter(v => v !== 15)
        .map(v => 2 * v);
        
console.log(result);
```

Or use the swiss knife of all array manipulations: [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var array = [12, 15, 19, 20],
    result = array.reduce((r, v) => v !== 15 ? r.concat(v): r, []);
        
console.log(result);
```

With some optimizations

```js
var array = [12, 15, 19, 20],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, v) {
        if (v !== 15) {
            r.push(2 * v);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
        
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I had never seen the `reduce()` that's a pretty neat way of doing it, thank you!

Comment: @Ian: It's also hideously inefficient, as given above, creating a **whole new array** for each iteration. If you want to use `reduce` for this (it doesn't gain you anything but a decrease in clarity), then: `filtered = original.reduce((r, v) => { if (v !== 15) { r.push(v); } return r; }, []);` so it's not copying the array each time.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 3):

`map` can't remove values. If you need to simultaneously `map` *and* `filter`, your options are:

1. `filter`, then `map`, e.g.:

   ```
   filteredNumbersArray = numbersArray.filter(function(v) { return v !== 15; })
                                      .map(function(v) { return v * 2; });
   ```

   or with ES2015+ syntax:

   ```
   filteredNumbersArray = numbersArray.filter(v => v !== 15)
                                      .map(v => v * 2);
   ```

   or
2. Write your own thing, probably:

   ```
   filteredNumbersArray = [];
   numbersArray.forEach(function(v) {
       if (v !== 15) {
           filteredNumbersArray.push(v * 2);
       }
   });
   ```

   or with ES2015+ syntax:

   ```
   filteredNumbersArray = [];
   for (const v of numbersArray) {
       if (v !== 15) {
           filteredNumbersArray.push(v * 2);
       }
   }
   ```

   (You can also [ab]use `reduce` here, but it doesn't gain you anything worth having, and costs clarity.)

   If it comes up a lot for you, give yourself a combined `map-and-filter` function that uses some special return value to indicate that the entry should be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Map doesn't remove values it just mutates them.
You could set the value to null but that is probably not your intent.

Filter might server you better
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
let numbersArray = [12,15,19,20],
filteredNumbersArray = numbersArray.filter(function(value)
{
    return value != 15
});
```

This would return an array without the number 15.